# List.fold order of arguments

Tags: .net, functional-programming, f#

Hi I am trying to understand the following code. This code's purpose is to count the number of times a prime factor appears. The `factors` function just finds the prime factors for a given number.

```
let smallArray = Array.Parallel.init 5 factors;;

let checkMap key map =
    match Map.tryFind key map with
    | Some i -> i
    | None -> 0

let incr map (key:int) = Map.add key ((checkMap key map) + 1) map

Array.fold (List.fold incr) Map.empty smallArray;;
```

Where I get stuck is the last line of the code. I don't know if it does Array.fold first or List.fold but my guess would be List.fold. The next step is then it applies the function `incr` to the small array and puts it into an empty map but the function `incr`takes 2 arguments and as far as I can see we are only giving it a map? Could someone explain this?

Comment: This code is written in a very confusing way which makes it hard to explain. It could be replaced with simply `smallArray |> Seq.concat |> Seq.countBy id |> Map`

Comment: The simpler implementation I gave above is much faster too for big arrays. I think this is because `Seq.countBy` uses mutable data structures (safely under the hood) rather than making many lookups and updates to immutable maps.

Answer (score 1):

Lets's first summarize the types of the functions involved here:

```fsharp
List.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T list -> 'State
Array.fold : ('State -> 'T -> 'State) -> 'State -> 'T [] -> 'State
incr : Map<int, int> -> int -> Map<int, int>
```

As we can see from its type, `List.fold` accepts a function with the same shape as `incr`, taking two arguments and returning a value of the same type as its first argument. Applying `incr` to `List.fold` will then yield a partially applied function with the following type, before substituting inferred types:

```fsharp
(List.fold incr) : 'State -> 'T list -> 'State
```

and after substituting `'State` and `'T` with the types that can be inferred form the application of `incr` we get:

```fsharp
(List.fold incr) : Map<int, int> -> int list -> Map<int, int>
```

This again has the same shape as `incr`, the only difference being that the second `int` argument of `incr` is an `int list` here. And since `Array.fold` has the same basic shape as `List.fold` we can use `(List.fold incr)` the same way we did with `incr` above, as the first argument of `Array.fold`.

`Array.fold (List.fold incr)`, if partially applied, would yield the type:

```fsharp
(Array.fold (List.fold incr)) : Map<int, int> -> int list [] -> Map<int, int>
```

`Map.empty` and `smallArray` is then applied to the last arguments as the initial value and collection to fold over, respectively, so that:

- `Array.fold` folds over `smallArray` with `(List.fold incr)`
- `List.fold incr` in turn folds over each `int list` in `smallArray`
- `incr` accumulates its results in the `Map<int, int>` that originates from the initial `Map.empty` value passed to `Array.fold`.